500 error when trying to log out of the vue3 laravel sanctum account
I have written an authentication form, login, registration and receipt of the user work for me, but logout does not work for me, the user can log into the account, but he can no longer log out.
So that I don't try to change it, but I still catch 500 errors and such a log in laravel: Method Illuminate\Auth\Request Guard::logout does not exist.
I looked at several discussions about this problem on various forums, but nothing helped there, but now I don't even understand if I can log out of my account in sanctum for SPA at all.
The file api.php:
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
   Route::post('/login', LoginController::class)->name('login');
   Route::post('/register', RegisterController::class)->name('register');
   Route::post('/logout', LogoutController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum');
   Route::get('/user', GetUserController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum');
});

The controller for the output:
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard("web")->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken(); 

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged out']);
}

And on the front in pinia there is such a code:
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', () => {
  const user = ref(null);

  const getCsrfToken = async () => {
    await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
  };

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await getCsrfToken(); // получаем CSRF токен
      await axios.post('/api/login', { email, password });
      await getUser(); // получаем информацию о пользователе
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const register = async (name, email, password) => {
    try {
      await getCsrfToken();
      await axios.post('/api/register', { name, email, password });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Registration error', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      // await getCsrfToken();
      const response = await axios.post('/api/logout');
      console.log('Ответ от API:', response);
      user.value = null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };


  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      await getCsrfToken();
      const response = await axios.get('/api/user');
      user.value = response.data;
      console.log(user.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Get user error', error);
      user.value = null;
    }
  };

  const isAuthor = computed(() => user.value?.role === "author");
  const isAdmin = computed(() => user.value?.role === "admin");

  return {
    user, isAuthor, isAdmin,
    login, register, logout, getUser,
  };
})

I did everything as it is written in the laravel sanctum documentation
There is either something not finished in the documentation, or I do not know.
I really don't want to leave such a disabled person on an account, but still make a normal one with the possibility of exit.
If someone has encountered such a problem and somehow solved it, then I will be glad to know how.

First, you need to understand that Sanctum has two features.
"API Token Authentication" and "SPA Authentication".
Do you really understand the difference between the two and which one you should use?
Currently you are using "SPA Authentication".
If you are sure that "SPA Authentication" is the right choice, then what you should do is use the Breeze API stack.
The Breeze API stack provides all the authentication functions for "SPA Authentication".
Writing your own authentication code is where the mistake is. The official Laravel starter kit is the most correct way to use it.

I'm doing this for the first time, so I don't really understand it yet, just in the documentation, that this is what you need to do for a SPA and I did it. It turns out that the way I write the authentication now is more suitable for the starter kit? And now it's better for me to redo authentication for the Breeze API by removing the old code?
